# Create custom UITableView separator line

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uiappearance

I would like to create a separator line like this one:

[image]

Any idea about how to implement it?
I tried getting an image of the line and using `UIAppearance` proxy objects:

```
[[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyController class], nil] setSeparatorColor:
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]]];
[[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyController class], nil] setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

but,somehow, only the black line gets rendered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try below:

```
UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separator.backgroundColor = myColor;
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator];
```

or

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 1);
   [customCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

   return customCell;
}
```

Comment: I believe your last line is:     [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator];

anyway it doesn't work because I need a separator line with two colors

Comment: how to add an image instead?

Comment: I think the second approach works better but I had to set 
CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 1)

Comment: Strange that I cannot get the same effect with the UIAppearance proxy objects

Comment: By the way it is an image background up there either for the cell or the whole table.

Comment: I did this trick for a one of my app before, it was a static UITable and I put a pre designed background for the table and remove the separator and the cell bg ;)

Comment: when I use appearance proxy I just get a black line

Comment: What happens if the cell is reused? Shouldn't you check if the separator view exists already?

Comment: You may want to use `1.0 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale` as the separator height.

Answer (score 8):

@Tarek
I used two instance of your objects for creating the double line

```
UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 0.5, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
UIView *separator2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
separator2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator2];
```

Looks good! Kudos for you

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

viewDidLoad:

```
//remove default separator line
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

tableView cell:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: bounds.size.height - 0.5, width: bounds.size.width - 22, height: 1))
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        contentView.addSubview(separator)
    }
}
```